# Code using facebook php sdk stopped working suddenly - what happened?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an old piece of php code calling Facebook, that **used to work fine until a week ago.** Now it suddenly stopped working. Here are the relevant lines involved:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v562/autoload.php';

// -- skipping here less relevant lines --

// Initialize Facebook Environment:
$default_graph_version = 'v2.10';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => $default_graph_version
]);

// Redirect to phase2 for facebook login:
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$fbPermissions = ['manage_pages', 'publish_pages'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($phase2_url, $fbPermissions);
header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
```

Now upon reaching the `header` line, I get: *"Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."* -- I have a feeling (not sure) it has to do with using old versions of things? Has something changed in the recent days (May 2022)?

EDIT:
I've made certain updates in order to match new Graph API version. I used *compose* to download the new php sdk, I modified the `require_once` accordingly, and I modified `v2.10` to `v13.0`. **I still get the exact same error**.
I checked the value of `$loginUrl` that gives me the error after redirection, and it is (shortened): `https://www.facebook.com/v13.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=[***]&state=[***]&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.7.0&redirect_uri=[my correct url]&scope=manage_pages%2Cpublish_pages`

Comment: They may have sunset the version you were using. According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog , the Graph API 6.0 was available until 6 days ago. I would suggest upgrading to a newer version. Also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/versioning

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/publish_pages: _"On May 5, 2020, we released six new Page permissions to replace the manage_pages and publish_pages permissions."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but omitting the "permissions" argument to `getLoginUrl` altogether -- solved the issue.